# Perl script in bash's HereDoc

Tags: perl, bash

Is possible *somewhat* write a perl script in a bash script as heredoc?

This is not working (example only)

```
#/bin/bash
perl <<EOF
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print "xxx: $_\n";
}
EOF
```

Is here some nice way how to embed a perl script into a bash script? Want run perl script from an bash script and don't want put it into external file.

Comment: Don't you need some command line switches after the name of the executable? Such as `perl -we`?

Comment: @TLP No, OP is just passing the script as standard input.

Answer (score 27, accepted):

The problem here is that the script is being passed to perl on stdin, so trying to process stdin from the script doesn't work.

#### 1. String literal

```
perl -e '
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print "xxx: $_\n";
}
'
```

Using a string literal is the most direct way to write this, though it's not ideal if the Perl script contains single quotes itself.

#### 2. Use `perl -e`

```
#/bin/bash

script=$(cat <<'EOF'
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print "xxx: $_\n";
}
EOF
)
perl -e "$script"
```

If you pass the script to perl using `perl -e` then you won't have the stdin problem and you can use any characters you like in the script. It's a bit roundabout to do this, though. Heredocs yield input on stdin and we need strings. What to do? Oh, I know! This calls for `$(cat <<HEREDOC)`.

Make sure to use `<<'EOF'` rather than just `<<EOF` to keep bash from doing variable interpolation inside the heredoc.

You could also write this without the `$script` variable, although it's getting awfully hairy now!

```
perl -e "$(cat <<'EOF'
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print "xxx: $_\n";
}
EOF
)"
```

#### 3. Process substitution

```
perl <(cat <<'EOF'
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print "xxx: $_\n";
}
EOF
)
```

Along the lines of #2, you can use a bash feature called process substitution which lets you write `<(cmd)` in place of a file name. If you use this you don't need the `-e` since you're now passing perl a file name rather than a string.

Comment: Second problem: `$_` is interpolated by the shell, probably to an empty string. Escape it ... `print "xxx: \$_\n";`

Comment: It can only be used once per file, but perl's `-x` flag can be used with less than ugly results.

Comment: @john-kugelman is it possible to use Bash's variables inside Perl code via `heredoc`?

Comment: @sdkks Inside perl script, you can use exported bash variables $ENV{variable},   e.g. set | perl -lne 'print if m/$ENV{HOME}/;'

Answer (score 4):

You know I never thought of this.

The answer is "**YES!**" it does work. As others have mentioned, `<STDIN>` can't be used, but this worked fine:

```
$ perl <<'EOF'
print "This is a test\n";
for $i ( (1..3) ) {
print "The count is $i\n";
}
print "End of my program\n";
EOF
This is a test
The count is 1
The count is 2
The count is 3
End of my program
```

In Kornshell and in BASH, if you surround your end of here document string with single quotes, the here document isn't interpolated by the shell.

Comment: @JohnKugelman I mentioned that you can't use STDIN in my post. The question was "_Is possible somewhat write a perl script in a bash script as heredoc_". Not whether you can read from STDIN or not. The answer is yes, it does work.

Comment: You can use STDIN if you define a specific FD and use it's linked device file: `echo 'foo' | perl /dev/fd/3 3<<-'EOPERL'`

Answer (score 2):

Only small corection of @John Kugelman's answer. You can eliminate the useless `cat` and use:

```
read -r -d '' perlscript <<'EOF'
while(<>) {
    chomp;
    print "xxx: $_\n";
}
EOF

perl -e "$perlscript"
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's another way to use a PERL HEREDOC script within bash, and take full advantage it.

```
    #!/bin/sh
    #If you are not passing bash var's and single quote the HEREDOC tag
    perl -le "$(cat <<'MYPL'
    # Best to build your out vars rather than writing directly
    # to the pipe until the end.
    my $STDERRdata="", $STDOUTdata="";
    while ($i=<STDIN>){ chomp $i;
        $STDOUTdata .= "To stdout\n";
        $STDERRdata .= "Write from within the heredoc\n";
    MYPL
    print $STDOUTdata; #Doing the pipe write at the end
    warn $STDERRdata;  #will save you a lot of frustration.
    )" [optional args] <myInputFile 1>prints.txt 2>warns.txt
```

or

```
    #!/bin/sh
    set WRITEWHAT="bash vars"
    #If you want to include your bash var's
    #Escape the $'s that are not bash vars, and double quote the HEREDOC tag
    perl -le "$(cat <<"MYPL"
    my $STDERRdata="", $STDOUTdata="";
    while (\$i=<STDIN>){ chomp \$i;
        \$STDOUTdata .= "To stdout\n";
        \$STDERRdata .= "Write $WRITEWHAT from within the heredoc\n";
    MYPL
    print \$STDOUTdata; #Doing the pipe write at the end
    warn \$STDERRdata;  #will save you a lot of frustration.
    )" [optional args] <myInputFile 1>prints.txt 2>warns.txt
```