# Parse Output of Command into Variable LIVE (Network Traffic Monitoring)

Tags: macos, bash, perl, sed, grep

I am writing a network monitoring script in bash. The base command I am using is `ettercap -T -M ARP -i en1 // //`. Then I pipe `egrep --color 'Host:|GET'` into it.

A sample output I am getting looks like this:

```
GET /images/srpr/logo11w.png HTTP/1.1.
Host: www.google.com.
GET /en-us/us/products HTTP/1.1.
Host: www.caselogic.com.
```

My desired output is this:

```
Title: logo11w.png
URL: www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png HTTP/1.1.

Title: Products - Case Logic
URL: www.caselogic.com/en-us/us/products
```

Things to notice: `HTTP/1.1.` and the `.` at the end of the host are gone. They also are formed into one `URL` and there is a blank line after each `Title`/`URL` listing. I attempted forming them into one URL by parsing the commands output into a variable with

```
var=`sudo ettercap -T -M ARP -i en1 // // | egrep --color 'Host:|GET'` | echo $var
```

but obviously that doesn't work because the input to the variable is a command the isn't done until the user requests a stop (`CTRL + C`).

To get the title of an HTML page, I use the command `wget -qO- 'https://url.goes/here' |   perl -l -0777 -ne 'print $1 if /<title.*?>\s*(.*?)\s*<\/title/si'`. If it is something that doesn't have a title, such as an image, no title is fine.

Any help is greatly appreciated, and sorry if what I wrote is hard to read, feel free to ask questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

**title_host.pl**

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use warnings;
use strict;
use WWW::Mechanize;

my $mech = WWW::Mechanize->new();

my ($get,$host,$title);
while (<>) {
    if (m|^GET (\S+) |) {
        $get = $1;
    } elsif ( m|^Host: (\S+)\.| ) {
        $host = $1;
    } else {
        # Unrecognized line...reset
        $get = $host = $title = '';
    }

    if ($get and $host) {
        my ($title) = $get =~ m|^.*\/(.+?)$|; # default title
        my $url = 'http://' . $host . $get;
        $mech->get($url);
        if ($mech->success) {
            # HTML may have title, images will not
            $title = $mech->title() || $title;
        }
        print "Title: $title\n";
        print "URL: $url\n";
        print "\n";

        $get = $host = $title = '';
    }
}
```

**input**

```
GET /images/srpr/logo11w.png HTTP/1.1.
Host: www.google.com.
GET /en-us/us/products HTTP/1.1.
Host: www.caselogic.com.
```

**now just pipe your input into the perl script:**

```
cat input | perl title_host.pl
```

**output:**

```
Title: logo11w.png
URL: http://www.google.com/images/srpr/logo11w.png

Title: Products - Case Logic
URL: https://www.caselogic.com/en-us/us/products
```

Comment: Thanks, I'll try it out!

Comment: Is there anyway that I can include the Perl in the bash script to make it portable? If not, that's fine.

Comment: Yes, you can include the perl script in a heredoc: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17751199/perl-script-in-bashs-heredoc

Comment: Thank you so much! Worked like a charm!

Comment: Well, never mind. Piping anything into a file instead of a command, gives me the error `-bash: io.pl: command not found`

Comment: You realize that a script that provides a command needs to be (1) in your PATH, and (2) granted executable permissions? There are plenty of questions and answers already here describing the necessary steps.