# Network Monitor: Don't Show Same Line Immediately Twice

Tags: macos, bash, perl, sed, grep

I am building a networking monitoring script in bash. The base command is:

```
sudo ettercap -T -M ARP -i en1 /// | egrep --color Referer:
```

My output looks like

```
* |==================================================>| 100.00 %

Referer: http://www.apple.com/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/.
Referer: http://www.apple.com/diversity/.
```

My desired output is:

```
* |==================================================>| 100.00 %

Title: Apple
URL: http://www.apple.com/

Title: Apple - Diversity - Inclusion inspires innovation.
URL: http://www.apple.com/diversity/
```

Notice: `.` at the end of a Referer is no longer there, `Referer` is changed to `URL`, `Title` is added based on title of HTML page and there is a new line every `Title` `URL` pair. In my [previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32174907/parse-output-of-command-into-variable-live-network-traffic-monitoring), I was provided with a perl script to do something along these lines, however `ettercap` didn't always show a `Host:` and `GET` line, so I am retrying with it's constant `Referer` line. I am not familiar with perl at all, so I am unable to edit myself. **If you could comment what everything does, that would make it easier for me to learn.**

**Any help is greatly appreciated, thanks!**

Comment: Also, this is very much in "please write my program for me" territory, and that's not what we do here.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy I do know how, but it didn't end up working.

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth What didn't end up working? I don't see any code posted...

Comment: @MattJacob The perl script worked, but ettercap wouldn't output correctly, so I decided to use a different ettercap output: referer. This requires modification to the perl script

Comment: @SkylerSpaeth I bet it did require some modifications to a Perl script, **which you need to show us if you expect to get any help**. As Charles already told you, we're not going to write your code for you.